# How to find correct version of 'Wave' for ReSharper extension?

Tags: plugins, package, version, resharper

I created a small R# extension. When I tried to publish it I had a very hard time to find which version of 'Wave' I should add. Before I had "[7.0,7.1)", now it I use "8.0", but is it correct? There is some numbering [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Extensions/PlatformVersioning.html), but it does not include minor versions...

Answer (score 0):

Wave 8.0 is ReSharper 2017.1.x. There are no minor versions for wave numbers, and each minor version of ReSharper (e.g. 2017.1 and 2017.2) get a full increment of wave (e.g. wave 8.0 and 9.0). There are no new wave versions for maintenance releases - e.g. 2017.1.1 is the same wave as 2017.1.2. These are bug fixes only, and there are no API changes.